# Custom ECB dropdown menu API?

Tags: ecb-menu, object-model, client-object-model

In 2010 (or 2007) is there a server control that is responsible for rendering of ECB menus?  For example, if I wanted to create a custom UI for a Document Library (**NOT** using XSL/DataViewWebPart/etc), and wanted to still create the same "ECB dropdown menu experience", is there a control I can leverage?

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119115220/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx). It applies to adding a custom menu to an SPGridView, but I am sure you can use it.